# how to know whether ".target2" is applied to a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, css

```
<a id="test" class="target1 target2">test</test>
```

How to know whether $("#test") has applied .target2 or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use jQuery [hasClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/hasClass)

```
if( $("#test").hasClass("target2") ) 
{
    // yep, it has...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to know or do you want to do something if it has?

In the latter case, this will do nicely:

```
$("#test.target2").doWhateverYouWantToDo(...);
```